# ES6 circular dependency in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've just set up a little test project using react native. It's all new to me (including ECMAScript 6). Eslint is telling me something about "circular dependencies" and i don't know how to solve this problem. The code is working nevertheless.

my package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.4.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.4.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "24.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "jest": "24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
},
...
```

---

`src/index.jsx` is the main JSX file:

```
import { Comp1 } from 'components';
...
```

---

I created a `src/components/index.jsx` to enable imports like

```
import { Comp1, Comp2, Comp3 } from 'components'
```

instead of

```
import { Comp1 } from 'components/comp1';
import { Comp2 } from 'components/comp2';
import { Comp3 } from 'components/comp3';
```

The file `src/components/index.jsx` looks like:

```
export * from './button';
export * from './comp1';
...
```

---

`src/components/button/index.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import style from './style';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {
  const {
    buttonStyle,
    textStyle
  } = style;

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default Button;
export { Button };
```

---

`src/components/comp1/index.jsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'components';
import style from './style';

const Comp1 = (props) => {
  const {
    textStyle,
    viewStyle
  } = style;

  return (
    <View style={viewStyle}>
      <Text style={textStyle}>some text</Text>
      <Button>Test</Button>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Comp1;
export { Comp1 };
```

Running this setup produces an eslint error [import/no-cycle](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/v2.17.3/docs/rules/no-cycle.md). The code itself works.

If i change `import { Button } from 'components'` in `src/components/comp1/index.jsx` into `import { Button } from 'components/button'` the no eslint error pops up.

I would like to use this short import syntax like described above without loosing the possibility of using the modules inside of each other. Is there a way?

Comment: What is the runtime structure of this code? Are you transpiling to CommonJS (e.g., `require` calls), or leaving the ESM (`import` and `export` declarations) in the transpiled result the browser sees?

Comment: Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge to check for these kind of errors, very useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Honestly i don't know if CJS or ESM is generated in react native projects. I only know that babel is used here for transpiling the code. "Babel [...] is *mainly* used to convert ECMAScript 2015+ code into a backwards compatible version of JavaScript" (see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder [Facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html) is telling me that [JavaScriptCore](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore) is used in react native apps which currently implements ​ECMAScript as in ​[ECMA-262 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). Does that automatically mean we're talking about ESM here? Does anyone know?

Comment: I know that JavaScriptCore supports ESM, but that doesn't necessarily mean React Native is using it, esp. since React Native predates JavaScriptCore's support of ESM. (Sorry, haven't played with React Native yet.) I would expect it to be possible to look at the actual transpiled .js files to see what module syntax they use...

Comment: @FernandoMontoya Thanks for the link. Funny thing: madge doesn't complain while eslint does.

Comment: @iwanuschka - That makes me wonder if madge is reading these files correctly. There is definitely a cyclic dependency above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your structure *is* setting up a cyclic dependency between `components/index.jsx` and `comp1/index.jsx` (and others where you have this same thing). `comp1/index.jsx` imports from `components/index.jsx`, which imports from `comp1/index.jsx`.

The runtime handling of cycles is different between actual native ESM¹ modules and CJS² or similar. Both require careful handling of cycles, but the ways they behave differ slightly. This can be particularly confusing if you're transpiling ESM to CJS in your bundler or similar.

When there's a cyclic dependency between two modules (to keep it simple), it means at some point one of the two modules will run before the other, which means any imports it takes from the other will either be uninitialized (ESM) or not yet be defined (CJS). So *top-level code* in one of the two modules can't rely on the imports existing yet. In ESM, trying to use an uninitialized export raises an error; in CJS, the export's value is just `undefined`.

In your example, I wouldn't expect that to be a problem, because the top-level code in the modules in the cycle doesn't use the imports from the other module in the cycle, it's only used in functions called later (`comp1/index.jsx` uses `Button`, but only when `Comp1` is *called*, and it's not called at the top-level code. (The process can be more complicated than that, but...)

If the code is tested and working, you might use [configuration comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-configuration-comments) to disable that rule for the component files (if it lets you do that). This lets you leave the rule on globally in case of actually-problematic cycles, but not get bothered about these cycles you've tested and know are good.

---

¹ ESM = **E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules, genuine native JavaScript modules, which are statically analyzable if you use only `import` and `export` declarations (not `import()` dynamic imports).

² CJS = **C**ommon**JS**, a dynmic module structure using `require` and an `exports` object.

Comment: I've got it now. Probably. To be able to export a module like `export * from './button';` it needs to be imported, which is done automatically here. Haven't thought about it that way. Like this it goes round and round. But anyway, the only solution here would be to throw away the `index.jsx` containing all the exports and to use import statements like `import { Comp1 } from 'components/comp1';`?

Comment: @iwanuschka - Not necessarily. I was editing the answer as you commented. :-)

Comment: how to disable this rule for entire project though?

Comment: @theprogrammer - I assume you can disable it in [your configuration](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) like any other rule.

Comment: I tried giving "no-cycle":off in rules, but its not working. I am not sure what key-value pair i need to give in the rules section in my .eslintrc.json file

Comment: @theprogrammer - Me either. I think it may be `import/no-cycle`.